# Secure WS endpoint for methods TRACE, HEAD, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, PUT

Tags: web-services, jboss, jboss-eap-7

after migration from Jboss EAP 6.4 to EAP 7.1 I notice the following message in server log:

```
09:39:48,847 WARN  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) UT015020: Path /HeatManager is secured for some HTTP methods, however it is not secured for [TRACE, HEAD, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, PUT]

09:39:48,848 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYUT0021: Web-Kontext registriert: "/heat-ws" für Server "default-server"
```

HeatManager is a webservice declared in java class as

```
@WebService(name = "HeatManager", targetNamespace = Configuration.WEBSERVICE_NAMESPACE + "HeatManager", portName = "HeatManagerSOAP")
```

and in jboss-webservices.xml as

```
<context-root>heat-ws</context-root>
<port-component>
<ejb-name>HeatManagerImpl</ejb-name>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
<secure-wsdl-access>true</secure-wsdl-access>
</port-component>
```

How can I secure all these methods for my endpoint?

Comment: can you please add the content of your web.xml